# Implementing BST TREE DUPLICATES KEYS - JS

Tags: javascript, data-structures, binary-search-tree, javascript-objects

I'm trying to implement a self balancing tree (beginning with BST first ).
So i have multiple keys with same value. So i have decided to make primary and secondary comparison to place a value in a node.

My node structure looks like ->

```
var Node = function (value) {
    this.fine = value.fine ; // primary comparison 
    this.index = value.index ; // secondary comparison 
    this.left = null ;
    this.right = null ;
};
```

fine is int value and index is array index.

my BST insert looks like this->

```
function insert(root, data) {
    if(root == null) { 
        root = new Node(data)
    }

  // base case for secondary comparison . 
    if(root.fine === data.fine ) {
        if(root.index  > data.index ) { 
          root.left = new Node(data) ;
        } else { 
          root.right = new Node(data)
        }
      }

     
    if(root.fine > data.fine ) { 
      root.left = insert(root.left, data) ;
    } else if(root.fine < data.fine ) {
      root.right =  insert(root.right , data) ;
   
  
  
    return root;
}
```

but i am getting MAXIMUM STACK CALL. i think the base case is not right!  What should be the base case of this problem?

Comment: You should indent your code. You terminated insert function at line number 5.

Comment: How are you calling this function? Provide [mcve] preferably in a running snippet.